# Tool Tips from stored content and implementing site wide

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application, we want our Admins of the application to manage tool tips for controls on the page for instance: text boxes, list boxes, etc. The tool tips will stored in a table structure and each view will load the respective tool tip data.

So I created the following table, Admin users will go to the admin menu and add/update tool tips for a given controller/model fields.

**Entity** : *ToolTip*

```
  public class ToolTip
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string ControllerName { get; set; }

        public string ToolTipMessage { get; set; }

        public string FormField { get; set; }
    }
```

I need some advice on the design. For instance every time I add a new field I would have to update the tool tip admin page and add the new field.  I see allot of maintenance for this tool.  Also as far as retrieving a tool tip when a user hovers on the respective user control, I have seen some examples where people load via AJAX tool tip content but I was wondering if that is a good approach.  Every time a user hovers on a control an AJAX request has to be made to the server.

I was thinking when a model is rendered, I could fetch the tool tip data and hidden fields and then the control can pick it up.  What do you guys think about my approach

or

instead of creating a seperate admin menu to manage these tool tips, i can enable the admins to manage the tool tip in the views itself.

Comment: How many tips are you going to be loading?